# For loop in my collide function never hitting?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a tile based game in pygame and I can't quite get my collision function work. So far I have it that when I hit WASD it checks if it is a valid move before actually moving the sprite.

```
    def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        print("TEST" + str(self.collide_with_walls(dx, dy)))
        if not self.collide_with_walls(dx, dy):
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy
```

This is my move function that calls my collide function (Figured I would include it just in case)

```
def collide_with_walls(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        print("Here 1")
        print(self.game.walls)
        for wall in self.game.walls:
            print("2")
            if wall.x == self.x + dx and wall.y == self.y + dy:
                print("Hit wall")
                return True
            print("No hit wall")
        return False
```

This is my collide function that is constantly returning false. Important to note that it is never printing "2" so it is never getting in the for loop and when I print out 'self.game.walls' it prints "<Group(0 sprites)>

```
class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

And here lies the Wall function that places the wall where I have a hunch that the problem is but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice helps :)

Comment: what is the output of this `print(self.game.walls)`?

Comment: Just a test to see what is stored in there considering how it was getting to the collision function but never into the for loop

Comment: i mean does it printing anything?

Comment: What class of object is self.game.walls supposed to be? A list-like of Walls?

Comment: It prints <Group(0 sprites)>. I wrote most of this a year ago so not entirely sure but I've been under the impression it was a list. EDIT: When I printed out the type of it I got <class 'pygame.sprite.Group'>

Comment: Might `<Group(0 sprites)>` indicate that there are no sprites (i.e. walls) in the group? So you never enter the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) a and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) or [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)  for the collision test. For instance:

```py
def collide_with_walls(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        
        new_rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (self.x + dx, self.y + dy))
        
        for wall in self.game.walls:
           
            if new_rect.colliderect(wall.rect):  
                print("Hit wall")
                return True
           
        return False
```

Comment: The problem is in my self.game.walls, I can't get to the collision detection part because the for loop never runs.

Comment: @GavinTynan So if the walls are not in `self.game.walls`, where are they?

Comment: Who knows ¯\_(ツ)_/¯